# Raspbian dpkg error /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, apt, dpkg

I have just installed raspbian for my raspberry pi and I tried to install fswebcam with sudo apt-get install fswebcam and I get the error:

```
dpkg: error: syntax error in file triggers file `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I then thought about doing an update so did:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This also produces the same error:

```
dpkg: error: syntax error in file triggers file `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

The packages download but can not install.

Here is the cat of the file and it does seem wrong:

```
/usr/sharm/Ijbo0knsvadm-infO
▒e;{▒my
@▒q▒}db+/}sR+sh!reman man-db/uw▒>l▒caMom`O▒m!f)Er
/u3z/locax+#rcre/ma~--d▒
'6sZ/▒%▒Z6/maN ▒sn%ef▒e▒d/mqn`eaN-▒2
-T{3/,HbNarL-m(j▒Y▒gn?dabihF/▒yn/▒o▒u▒7s li▒g▒+b`.p%0;a▒m`f
)▒ks/lib/miG*mk▒En▒c lyb'dib2.-▒*armhf
/As▒5rx▒2E/▒xib-0.8.3c▒▒e"! ,cbomib2n0=zirmh/muk/Scil0ag/d%cAs▒o}sp%d@g/mime/packages miLe)cwrxfst
-u{s▒!▒kJ%/mho▒'qackawe;(S▒a▒'d▒m+/e-info
.5▒rlibog$j▒▒92bufm2.▒?:-1 ▒l▒qders libedc,pixbu&2.-2▒BiHf▒u▒b/diB)Az▒=nifT8▒wOuea▒ih$-gmj▒u▒.@}▒"▒`'2.10.0/loadgR{▒|i"gdN-@j▒▒▒f2.0-0>abolf-usr/s▒ar'/▒o▒6sb▒/n6Bonf+gusr-s``ve?ehosdw▒h{:5'fkod▒ g▒▒4!nO▒ig
/ts▒?{(I▒e->mYIf▒v▒nT1▒f4K▒nf+g
/usr/mi▒o▒rLoliNu▒=▒~u%abHHdlj▒:.0&▒▒ .0m▒mmduleS0▒9kg▒k:.)0:armh/}rr.l▒b/gtk-2.1/▒.10/p▒yL-gdules`liCgtk2.0d0▒D▒-(,+/ts▒'sHe2e-Bxymicatmozs0ndsktop-film,W▒a▒c
/usb/3``r▒/gcknv-defa}~D?▒o▒=▒f2X/5krH3▒u/▒c/,▒▒#~d!|opy(&Cg▒V4
/pSf-shaRe▒wcgnF+skhUi!{ gco~▒s▒5{r>u(a3e/Qo0pl▒r ;p▒f
/u3r.L▒▒prm-diFqX)gnuepb▒`f/gti-;o0/▒.l▒?iLmkve&Ls|▒0gTk▒#-0:qr-`f
w/0▒3~2./im▒od7|e,▒i`guk▒3-`*!Ex▒▒msr/sjarD▒unu!mandJ▒urR/▒yB/▒unu menu
/etc▒ee▒q-/eDH▒▒c }e.=
/Tsr/sha▒e/kcoos▒x▒color xi"▒▒o0-icon-theiesR▒y▒▒uoxc▒f3'gNo▒u onNme-i#on
▒▒e/'
```

I would prefer not having to re-install raspbian but I will if I must

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end I unfortunately had to format the sd card and reinstall raspbian. The output of the file is a lot more comprehensive now. I will put the contents at a later date.